# Calender with marked dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp

I need to mark calendar date range as it is marked in stackoverflow - visited feature in profile.

[image]

Currently I am using bootstrap date picker.
Can we mark multiple dates in bootstrap date picker.

```
  $('#from_date').datepicker({
            todayBtn: 'linked',
            todayHighlight: true,
            format: "dd-M-yyyy",
            todayHighlight: true,
            orientation: "auto",
            endDate: '+0d',
            autoclose: true
        });
```

If yes, can you help me with the same.

If not please suggest some jquery plugin compatible with bootstrap 3.

Comment: may i know which bootstrap datepicker you are using?

Comment: This will help you: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/index.html

Comment: it looks like its possible refer [this](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/markup.html#date-range)

Answer (score 1):

By using this [Date-picker](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) you can write your code like this

first define your datepicker as a multidate pic.

```
 // if you have a JSON Array of
//dates in mm-dd-yyyy format

var data= ['5-5-2014','5-15-2014','5-25-2014'];

var dates=[];

for( i=0 ; i<data.length;i++)
{
    console.log(data[i]);
    dates.push(new Date(data[i]));
}

$('.date').datepicker({
    multidate: true
});

console.log(dates);

$('.date').datepicker('setDates', dates);
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/51cfb3sg/10/)

Comment: Thanks Aminul, can you please help me as how can I pass these dates dynamically? I am getting these dates in json array in format dd-mon-yyyy